# GIT status check only content changes, ignore attributes

Tags: git, attributes, mysql

I'm making backup of my project every 5 minutes during development. Made a small script and added to cron.

```
cd /var/www/sql-backup
mysqldump --routines -u root --password="<pwd>" <db> --ignore-table=tems.session > db1.temp.sql;
mysqldump -u root --password="<pwd>" -d <db> session > db2.temp.sql;
cat db1.temp.sql db2.temp.sql > backup.sql;
cd /var/www
if [ -n "$(git status --porcelain)" ]; then
        git add -A .;
        git commit -m "daily backup";
        git push;
else
  echo "no changes";
fi
```

Now the problem is, mysqldump every time renews file. Even if content is the same, file creation time changes. That's why it commits every time even if there is no data change. I want to prevent commit everytime.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: You can find diff between old dump and the new one. And delete the new one if there is no difference (before git)

Comment: @demas how it will look like in code?

Comment: You can grep both files, something like this: `grep -Fxvf file.old file.new`